What is the integral of $\frac{2x+3}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+4)+1}$
I am trying to solve integration problems but getting stuck with many problems.
The above question is asked in Wolfram Alpha and answer is given as
$$\int \frac{2 x + 3}{x (x + 1) (x + 2) (x + 4) + 1} dx =\sum_{ω^4 + 7 ω^3 + 14 ω^2 + 8 ω + 1=0}\frac{2 ω\log(x - ω) + 3\log(x - ω)}{4 ω^3 + 21 ω^2 + 28 ω + 8} + c.$$
Can anyone tell me the process?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Before asking any question search it in Approach zero website https://approach0.xyz/search/

Apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure. (First calculate the denominator, and its derivative.)

Actually I don't know how to use MathJax and Approach zero

Hint: notice that the denominator be written as
$$x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+1=k^2(k-\frac{1}{k}+1)^2$$, where $t=x-1$
After substituting the value of $k$ in the integrand, we get and easy to simplify integral with direct formulas, which I am sure you can do.

Your answer doesn't address the question which is : how can be explained the form of the primitive function given by Wolfram Alpha.
